# What is the difference between "aes(..., stat=count)" and "aes(...), stat="count"

Tags: r, ggplot2

take this dataset:

```
   demo <- tribble(
  ~cut,         ~freq,
  "Fair",       1610,
  "Good",       4906,
  "Very Good",  12082,
  "Premium",    13791,
  "Ideal",      21551
)

#There is no difference between this:
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, group = 1), stat = "count")
#and this:
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = stat(count), group = 1))
```

However, if you replace "count" with "prop", only the later command works, the former returning an error. Why is this? why does it work for count and not prop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`count` and `prop` are two variables computed by `geom_bar` when using `stat="count"`, and can be reached by `after_stat()`, `stat()` or `..count..`/`..prop..`:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = after_stat(count), group = 1), stat= "count")+
  geom_text(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = stat(count),label=round(..prop..,2),vjust=-1, group = 1),stat="count")
```

[image]
The other option is to use `stat="identity"`, in this case `prop` and `count` aren't calculated because values are left as is, without counting.

There's not `stat="prop"`, hence the error message you get.